# mod_secdownload not working when request comes from different server

Tags: php, lighttpd

Note: 110 KB picture will download once you click test1.

[test1](http://test1.x1c.org) hosted @ same server that hosts the files (dl5.nat.li)

[test2](http://test2.x1c.org) hosted @ external server, reports "Gone"

Why does test1 work, but test2 doesn't?

They both share the exact same **index.php**:

```
<?php
    $secret = "mysecret";
    $uri_prefix = "/dl/";
    $f = "/4615c7b8822f5a1187246e83ff3023698c70077a/badresults-ziggo.png";
    $t = time();
    $t_hex = sprintf("%08x", $t);
    $m = md5($secret.$f.$t_hex);
    $url = 'http://dl5.nat.li'.$uri_prefix.$m.'/'.$t_hex.$f;
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header( 'Location: '.$url ) ;
?>
```

Secdownload config on the file server:

```
  secdownload.secret          = "mysecret"
  secdownload.document-root   = "/home/dlfolder/"
  secdownload.uri-prefix      = "/dl/"
  secdownload.timeout         = 30
```

I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem went away after restarting lighttpd, I have no idea why or what was going on... odd.